# Possibility to background cache to a specific RMDatabaseCache from the RMTileCache?

Tags: caching, maps, mapbox, offline-caching

I want my users to be able to download multiple offline map areas and be able to access them through only one tilesource. My initial thought was to have a RMDatabaseCache for every area and add that to the RMTileCache.

I've tried several approaches to this, but run into different problems with them:

Approach 1: 
Add a RMDatabaseCache to the RMTileCache manager and start a beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource for that RMTileCache.

PROBLEM: It seems the tiles are always downloaded to the original(first) RMTileCache.db and not the one I just added. Is there a way to force the download to a specific tileCache in the tileCashes array?

Approach 2: Create a tempRMTileCache and start a beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource for that one and then add tempRMTileCache.tileCashes[0] to the original RMTileChache through addCache.

PROBLEM: The tempRMTileCache references the same RMTileCache.db as the original RMTileCache and there doesn't seem to be a way to change that. I tried to find a way to delete the original tileCashes array at index 0 and adding a new RMTileCache with specific path (thus forcing the download to the only existing RMDatabaseCache that I added) but removing a tileCashes item does not seem to be possible.

Am I going about this completely the wrong way? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `RMMapboxSource` to be `cacheable` ? Also what I did was inserting the `RMDatabaseCache` at first level using `insertCache(cache, atIndex: 0)`

Here's the full code, I tried it in offline mode, after downloading the tiles, worked like a charm

```
let database = RMDatabaseCache(usingCacheDir: false)
let mapView = RMMapView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.mapView = mapView
self.mapView.tileCache.insertCache(database, atIndex: 0)
self.mapView.delegate = self
self.mapView.hideAttribution = true
self.mapView.setZoom(kMapBoxDefaultZoom, animated: false)
self.mapView.setCenterCoordinate(kMapBoxCenterLocation, animated: false)
self.mapView.hidesMapboxLogo()

self.view.addSubview(self.mapView)
self.reloadMapView()

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    let onlineSource = RMMapboxSource(mapID: kMapBoxMapID)
    onlineSource.cacheable = true

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.mapView.addTileSource(onlineSource)
        let sw = self.mapView.pixelToCoordinate(CGPoint(x: 0, y: mapView.height))
        let ne = self.mapView.pixelToCoordinate(CGPoint(x: mapView.width, y: 0))
        let maxZoom = ceil(kMapBoxDefaultZoom).uint
        self.mapView.tileCache.beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource(onlineSource, southWest: sw, northEast: ne, minZoom: 0, maxZoom: maxZoom)
        self.delegate?.mapboxView?(mapView, didFinishloadingSource: onlineSource)
    }
}
```